# Getting video duration from blob in C#

Tags: c#

I have a webmethod that receives blobs that are parts of a video.
In this case I have three blobs. The first and second correspond to 10 seconds of the video each.
The third one is the final 5 seconds of the video.
So in total, I receive a video of 25 seconds in three blobs.
My problem is: when I save the three blobs into a single file on my disk, it does not have the duration of the video.
And the lack of this information is generating playback issues on this file.
On the playback bar it shows, for example, 0:22/0:00 instead of showing 0:22/0:25.

I am saving the file like this:

```
        const string blobA = @"\Publico\8BEF883850D70BDB2729D174CC6B3DB0\blob";
        const string blobB = @"\Publico\34C99D38A49BD6895156287980C6A4AF\blob";
        const string blobC = @"\Publico\2914FDF6E301A0F76DB8DE4CEEE31E9F\blob";
        const string caminhoDestino = @"C:\dev\arquivoTeste.webm";

        byte[] fileA = File.ReadAllBytes(blobA);
        byte[] fileB = File.ReadAllBytes(blobB);
        byte[] fileC = File.ReadAllBytes(blobC);

        List<byte> fileComplete = new List<byte>();
        fileComplete.AddRange(fileA);
        fileComplete.AddRange(fileB);
        fileComplete.AddRange(fileC);

        File.WriteAllBytes(path, fileComplete.ToArray());
```

Is there a way to get the duration of the video and save this information on the file?
Or a way to set this information on the file after saving it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"it does not have the duration of the video"* -- "it" who? Do you have any control over the code that cuts the original video up into the three blobs?

Comment: Well, without knowing exactly what the data and their precise format(!) in those blobs is, trying to blind-guess the cause and possible solution to your problem would be like a game of pinning the tail on the donkey. You should first determine exactly what the exact nature of those three blobs (their file format/internal data structure) is and whether it would actually be meaningful to simply concatenate them into a single file like you did...

Comment: It, the file. The file does not have the duration of the video. No, I dont have control over the code that cuts the original video. It is a javascript library that cuts the video and send the files to me.

I dont know the precise format of the blobs. But concatenating them is working. The video is working fine, the only problem is that I need a way to define the duration of the video. Then the playback bar would work too. Is there a way to set a header or something on the file containing the duration?

Comment: Read my comment again. I was not doubting that the media player wasn't unable to play the video stream(s) (media players often are quite capable in playing audio or video streams even if they are corrupted, or are in reality disparate video streams concatenated/"glued" together). The duration of a stream would need to be added to the meta data of whatever media file format is at play (pun intended) here. You just giving the file name the .webm extension is not solid evidence that the concatenated file in question is indeed an actual webm container...

Comment: If your data is indeed a webm container (again, i am not entirely certain that it is, see my last comment), i suggest you search the interwebs for a command line utility that can modify webm metadata. Since webm is based on mkv/Matroska, the mkvtoolnix utility package might work (i am not sure, but worth a try, i would say)

Comment: I will try it out. Thank you!